# User IP Nextjs getServerSideProps

Tags: reactjs, next.js

if you call API in getServerSideProps Nextjs, caller IP that will be sent to the API service is client IP or the server IP that runs Nextjs app??

appreciate your help

```
export const getServerSideProps = () => {
  //the ip of the sender is client or the server that runs nextjs app
  cont res = await axios.get('some url')
}
```

Comment: A request made from inside `getServerSideProps` is made from the server serving your Next.js app.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @juliomalves I think you are correct. I want to escape from the rate limiting of API service. is there any way to forward the client IP and prevent rate limiting?

Comment: `getServerSideProps` has access to a `req` object from its context which can potentially be used to retrieve the client's IP and forward it in the request you make from the server.

Comment: Use middleware functionality introduce by NextJS https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware

Answer (score 0):

NextJS client and server will share the IP address as this is part of src/pages folder.

Please refer [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction/)!

Comment: I read the docs but I couldn't find the specific sentence you mentioned. the main problem is if every request call in nextjs server will cause rate limiting error. is there any way to forward the client IP and prevent rate limiting?

Comment: the rate limit is API specific, you can create a middleware function where every API call will go through. How are getting rate limits on the client side?